# How can I remove a master or detail page from SplitApp?

Tags: sapui5

I add a master page by:

```
splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview(
  "clientiListMaster",
  "apps.appClienti.master.clientiListMaster"
));
```

Ok. my app work perfectly!

Now I want remove it from split app.. i try to do it by:

```
splitApp.removeMasterPage("clientiListMaster");
```

but after that, if I try to add once again the same page by:

```
splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview(
  "clientiListMaster",
  "apps.appClienti.master.clientiListMaster"
));
```

I have this error:

`2014-09-05 17:12:01 adding element with duplicate id 'clientiListMaster' -`

What is the problem...?

Comment: Did you try destroying the page after removing? duplicate id errors only make sense to me as long as an element exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
sap.ui.xmlview("clientiListMaster", "apps.appClienti.master.clientiListMaster")
```

is instantiating a view and giving it the id `clientiListMaster`.

You're doing it twice, which is what UI5 is complaining about. Instantiate it once and store a reference to it (e.g. in the controller) and then use that reference (to the single instance) when adding each time.

Comment: How can I control is the view is already instantiated?
I want do:

if(clientiListMaster not istantiated){
  instantiate the view
}

Comment: This is a different question to the one you asked and the one I answered. For this, you could follow the pattern I described in the answer anyway. An example is here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ViewSettingsDialog/code