# How load all local resource in a specific directory?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm developing by Openui5 a portal. My portal have 2 apps. I I have organized the code in folders:

```
root
  |
  |____app1
  |____app2
```

For example, in app1 directory I have some sub directory (misc, fragment, master, detail) and in detail folder I have a subfolder detail--->form.

To work, my project needs:

```
sap.ui.localResources("app1.misc");
sap.ui.localResources("app1.fragment");
sap.ui.localResources("app1.master");
sap.ui.localResources("app1.detail");
sap.ui.localResources("app1.detail.form");
```

I want write a function `getPaths(dir)`

```
var aPaths= getPaths("app1");
for( var i = 0; i < aPaths.length; i++) {
      var path=aPaths[i];
      sap.ui.localResources(path);
}
```

How can I implement the function?

Comment: I'm just wondering if you're planning on responding to answers to a previous question you posted, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689127/how-can-i-remove-a-master-or-detail-page-from-splitapp

Comment: See also this comment by Tim Gerlach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327875/how-to-handle-the-itempress-of-a-table/24361565#comment38447973_24327875

Comment: I agree with @qmacro. And in addition to that, please bear in mind "*[..] SO is not here to help individual users with their problems. It is here to create a useful repository of high quality questions and answers so that the entire programming community can benefit by being able to search through that repository of knowledge to solve their problems without needing to actually ask another person for help. SO happens to help users with their problems, when they are able to ask a question that happens to help SO accomplish it's actual goal.*" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254065/3270057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot do `getPaths(dir)` in client side javascript to get your server side file structure . These lines of codes are necessary.

`localResources` and `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath` is to [register component resources](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/9c5a9619f69f4a819f91fc89d9ff56f1.html). Another way is to use `data-sap-ui-resourceroots` tag.

```
<script
    id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    type='text/javascript'
    src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
    data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'

    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "app1" : "./",
        "misc" : "./misc",
        "fragment" : "./fragment",
        "master" : "./master",
        "detail" : "./detail",
    }' >
</script>
```